# "Edit with IDLE" not showing with a .pyw file

Tags: python, windows, regedit

I recently changed Python version, but "Edit with IDLE" was not shown when you right clicked on a Python file.

So I headed down into Regedit and changed this:

[image: regedit]

In both `Python.File\Shell\Edit with IDLE 3.8 (64-bit)` and `Python.NoConFile\Shell\Edit with IDLE 3.8 (64-bit)`, the file in `command` is filled with this:

```
"C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\pythonw.exe" -m idlelib "%L" %*
```

But the "Edit with IDLE" option is only shown with a .py file.

---

With a `.py` file:

[image: .py]

With a `.pyw` file:

[image: .pyw]

So my question is: Why doesn't ***Edit with IDLE*** show with `.pyw` files?

I tried reinstalling Python after completely removing it, rebooting (to see Regedit changes?) but nothing worked.
Any ideas?

---

**Edit**: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py` refers to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pyw` refers to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile` (didn't change that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem myself.

In fact, the description of a `.pyw` file in the Explorer was **"PYW file"**, so it wasn't attached to the `.pyw` in Regedit.

I don't know why, but because I attached the `.pyw` extension to

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\pythonw.exe
```

it wasn't attached to `.pyw` in Regedit.

So I simply clicked on "Open with" and chose

```
C:\Windows\pyw.exe
```

And everything worked.

---

**Edit**:

> I don't know why, but because I attached the `.pyw` extension to
>
> ```
>  C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\pythonw.exe
> ```
>
> it wasn't attached to `.pyw` in Regedit.

The `Python38` folder just didn't exist, I had to type `Python38-32`